# Starting Electron.exe or electron project - no BrowserWindow opens up

Tags: node.js, windows-10, electron

I've been trying to get an Electron program to work on my Windows 10 laptop, but I can't get the `BrowserWindow` to open, when I run the application from Visual Studio 2017 only the console opens up. And when I try to open the `Electron.exe` itself from the folders, nothing happens. The Electron-process can be seen in the task manager, though.

Since I get no errors or anything whatsoever, I'm really confused about this. What could "stop" Electron from showing any windows? Faulty code can't be the reason, since I've used the exactly same code from Electron quick start in my project, and opening `Electron.exe` doesn't require anything to be made by me.

**EDIT**: When I tried to make as simple Electron app as possible from zero in VS2017, I tried to put in `console.log()` commands everywhere to see what is called. The point where there was one log-command before and one log-command after `win = new BrowserWindow()` line, the one AFTER the `new BrowserWindow()` line didn't get put into the console. Or any other after that. There are no errors, warnings, anything to be seen. Two processes start, and one of them just disappears after a while.

**EDIT#2**: Options for `BrowserWindow` were just height and width `({width: 800, height: 600})` Nothing special there. BUT I noticed **one** thing after trying every Electron version manually: Every Electron version after 1.4.16 WILL NOT WORK on my computer. 1.5.0 and beyond will not let me create a new `BrowserWindow`. I don't know reason to this. What did they change in 1.5.0-> so that I can't open windows.

I tried to use breakpoints in VS, but as soon as the line where a new `BrowserWindow` is created is executed, the code execution just... "skips" over everything else. It doesn't go to the next breakpoint, it doesn't crash, it doesn't execute anything else, it doesn't throw any errors, it just, is. `Electron.exe` console is open, VS still shows that program is running but that's about it. This is really bizarre. Same happens when trying to run the [quick start app](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) from the command line with `npm start`.

Comment: How do you start example code? It is described in details here:https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/#run-your-app quick start apps project also link to this page in readme.

Comment: @pergy Hey. I did it like this today: git clone (that quick start repo) -> npm install -> npm start. It shows two Electron processes (main and rendered, I think) when it starts, but other disappears by itself after a while, and no window is seen. Also, I added one more thing I noticed to the post.

Comment: Can you put your `BrowserWindow` options in your post.

Comment: @MikeWood Hey, I added it to the post. Different versions of Electron seem to play part in this problem, but I don't know how.

Comment: Reinstalling electron worked for me `npm uninstall -g electron` then `npm install -g electron`

Comment: @MikeWood HI. If it were that simple, I wouldn't be here asking :c It doesn't matter where Electron is installed, or in which folder, I can't "run" it. For example the Electron.exe you get from GitHub (in the zip folder). It should start up a window that lets you drag apps you want to run with it to it when clicked. However, if the version is 1.5.0 or newer, no window appears. Only 2 processes show up, and one of them disappears after a few seconds. Normally ( with 1.4.16 or older) 3 processes show up, AND the window opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post answer here since I managed to work this out long time ago. For some reason, script just "stops" whenever it gets to section where new window instance is created.

The solution for this was to use setTimeout() with 0 delay, and put rest of the code under new function inside it. It may be something to do with race conditions, but I don't know about it. I found this solution through some random GitHub Issues-section comments.

Another thing: this issue seems to happen only when window is created when app is started, but not when, for example, you call function later on through UI button when app is already running.

```
// Works
setTimeout(function () {
        var newWindow = new BrowserWindow({options});
}, 0);

// Doesn't work
var newWindow = new BrowserWindow({options});
```